# Consulta Status NFe C#

Tags: c#, nfe

Estou tentando realizar a consulta de status do serviço para NFe 3.10 porem sempre está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> A solicitação HTTP está proibida com o esquema de autenticação de
>   cliente 'Anonymous'.

Estou utilizando Visual Studio 2012 e .NET Framework 4.5.

Estou usando o código abaixo, alguém saberia me informar se está faltando algo?

```
String caminho = "C:\\Arquivos\\Upload\\certificado.pfx";
String senha = "123456789";
X509Certificate2 certificado = new X509Certificate2(caminho, senha);

TConsStatServ statusServer = new TConsStatServ();
statusServer.versao = "3.10";
statusServer.tpAmb = TAmb.Item2;
statusServer.cUF = TCodUfIBGE.Item42;
statusServer.xServ = TConsStatServXServ.STATUS;

XmlDocument doc = ObjectToXMLDocument(statusServer);

nfeCabecMsg nfeCabecalho = new nfeCabecMsg();
nfeCabecalho.cUF = "42";
nfeCabecalho.versaoDados = "3.10";

NfeStatusServico2Soap12Client statusServicoClient = new NfeStatusServico2Soap12Client();
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endereco = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://homologacao.nfe.sefaz.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeStatusServico/NfeStatusServico2.asmx");
statusServicoClient.Endpoint.Address = endereco;
statusServicoClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificado;

var retorno = statusServicoClient.nfeStatusServicoNF2(ref nfeCabecalho, doc);
```

Pelo navegador ele me solicita o certificado e consigo ter acesso ao WS.
Já tentei utilizar as chamadas:

```
X509Certificate2 certificado = new X509Certificate2(caminho, senha, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endereco = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://homologacao.nfe.sefaz.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeStatusServico/NfeStatusServico2.asmx?WSDL");
```

Comment: Você está encontrando dificuldades somente na versão "3.10" ou na "2.00" também? Também, o CNPJ do certificado autorizado é o mesmo certificado que você está usando para chamar a consulta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme algumas pesquisas encontrei esse link:
http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/problemas-comuns-ao-consumir-web.html

Basicamente no meu arquivo `app.config` estava descrito da seguinte forma:

```
<binding name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpsTransport />
</binding>
```

Bastou adicionar a informação descrita no [link](http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/problemas-comuns-ao-consumir-web.html) e resolveu o problema:

```
<binding name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Digest" requireClientCertificate="true" />
</binding>
```

Comment: Em 2018, muito obrigado me ajudou muito!!

Answer (score 1):

Cristiano, pelo que vejo você está tentando montar no braço as configurações do `Endpoint` e do `Binding`, eu penei um pouco para conseguir fazer isso, pois tem uma série de configurações que são feitas do `web.config`.
Tenta usar

Configuração do `Bind`

```
public CustomBinding Binding
        {
            get
            {
                TextMessageEncodingBindingElement securityElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                securityElement.MaxReadPoolSize = 64;
                securityElement.MaxWritePoolSize = 16;
                securityElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12;
                securityElement.WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                securityElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
                securityElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
                securityElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
                securityElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
                securityElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;
                HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
                httpsTransport.ManualAddressing = false;
                httpsTransport.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
                httpsTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
                httpsTransport.AllowCookies = false;
                httpsTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
                httpsTransport.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
                httpsTransport.DecompressionEnabled = true;
                httpsTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
                httpsTransport.KeepAliveEnabled = true;
                httpsTransport.MaxBufferSize = 65536;
                httpsTransport.ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
                httpsTransport.Realm = "";
                httpsTransport.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
                httpsTransport.UnsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication = false;
                httpsTransport.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
                httpsTransport.RequireClientCertificate = true;
                CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, httpsTransport);
                return binding;
            }
        }
```

Configuração do `Endpoint`

```
private EndpointAddress RemoteAddress(NotaFiscalEletronicaEntity nfe)
    {
        string uri = "";
        if (nfe.TpAmb == TpAmbEnum.Homologacao)
            uri = "https://homologacao.nfe.sefaz.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeRetAutorizacao/NFeRetAutorizacao.asmx";
        else uri = "https://nfe.sefaz.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeRetAutorizacao/NFeRetAutorizacao.asmx";

        EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri);

        return remoteAddress;
    }
```

Usando

```
NfeRetAutorizacaoSoap12Client nfeRetAutorizacao = new NfeRetAutorizacaoSoap12Client(this.Binding, this.RemoteAddress(nfe));
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara o problema é autenticação no server da receita, eles pedem certificado a sua aplicação quando tentar se conectar a eles para consumir. Exemplo de binding do serviço 
**RecepcaoEventoSoap** que fica em seu App.config quando depois que adiciona o web servisse(sem certificado na sua máquina não é possível adicionar o web service):

```
   <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="RecepcaoEventoSoap">
               <security mode="Transport">
                   <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                   <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
               </security>
           </binding>
           <binding name="RecepcaoEventoSoap1"/>
       </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
```